# How to overwrite only explicitly specified keys, as a part of a map, in a config?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

In config/config.exs I have this:

```
config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: %{
    key1: "default-key1",
    key2: "default-key2",
    key3: "default-key3"
  }
```

And in config/dev.exs this:

```
config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: %{
    key1: "key1-dev-value",
  }
```

And in config/prod.exs this:

```
config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: %{
    key1: "key1-prod-value",
  }
```

I want that all the keys to remain all their initial values except those that I overwrite explicitly.

However, this code in `dev.exs` and `prod.exs`
will overwrite the `my_key` completely and thus there'll be only `key1` left and the other 2 - `key2` and `key3` will become gone.

How to fix it?

I don't consider to use a third-party library, nor env. variables, nor do I want to copy-paste the keys and their values from one config to the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @zwippie's answer is the best if your app owns the config you're setting and you're able to change the structure. If not, another option would be a `case` inside `config/config.exs`.

```rb
key1 =
  case config_env() do
    :prod ->
      "key1-prod-value"

    :dev ->
      "key1-dev-value"

    :test -> # or _env
      "default-key1"
  end

config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: %{
    key1: key1,
    key2: "default-key2",
    key3: "default-key3"
  }
```

Comment: [`config_env()`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#config_env/0) has been available since 1.11 and will save a lot of headaches later if switching to releases.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you use a Keyword list instead of a Map:

```
# config/config.exs

config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: [
    key1: "default-key1",
    key2: "default-key2",
    key3: "default-key3"
  ]

# config/dev.exs

config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: [
    key1: "key1-dev-value",
  ]
```

Fetch the configuration (in dev mode):

```
> Application.fetch_env(:my_app, :settings)
{:ok,
 [my_key: [key2: "default-key2", key3: "default-key3", key1: "key1-dev-value"]]}
```

Comment: A link to the docs explaining that would have been good. [Keyword lists are always deep-merged](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Config.html#config/2).

Answer (score 0):

Updating Maps can be done in [a few ways](https://dockyard.com/blog/2016/03/07/til-elixir-maps-have-built-in-syntax-for-updating) but I think this would work for config/prod.exs:

```
config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: %{my_key | key1: "key1-prod-value"}
```

Alternatively, there's perhaps a more readable option with:

```
config :my_app, :settings,
  my_key: Map.put(my_key, :key1, "key1-prod-value")
```

It would take the my_key defined already and update the pre-existing key1 within it, returning the full updated my_key map.